Multiple duplicated prepared statements using Rails + MySQL
We recently hit a limit of prepared statements in our MySQL DB, and after some digging I found that we are creating a really high amount of duplicates for the same prepared statement. For example:
mysql> select sql_text, count(*) from prepared_statements_instances group by 1 order by 2 desc limit 2;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| sql_text                                                                               | count(*) |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = ? ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT ? |      493 |
| SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = ? LIMIT ?                           |      490 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.09 sec)

We have 20+ statements with more than 300 duplicates, and each instance has been executed less than 10 times. From what I understand about prepared statements, they should be created once and then reused the next time that the query is ran, but that doesn't seem to be what's happening.
We are currently using MySQL 8.0.39 and Rails 6.1.7.9
Edit
I've also noticed that all entries in prepared_statements_instances for the same query have a different OWNER_THREAD_ID. Does each connection create a different instance of the same prepared statement?

We can only guess that this is caused by something in your Rails code. It sounds similar to the error reported here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5121. That was reported against Rails 3.x, but they didn't really fix the issue, they closed it with a suggestion to use a workaround of disabling prepared statements. I don't know if it was fixed in a more substantial way later.

I couldn't replicate that exact issue, so might be something different. I made an edit to the original question with some extra context on owner threads that could be useful

Yes, each thread corresponds to a different session, and prepared statements are not shared between sessions. So you must have a lot of distinct sessions each creating their own prepared statements.

Also, prepared statements don't survive after the end of a session, so you must have a lot of active sessions holding on to prepared statements.

Indeed that's the case, we have ~200 pods with 12 threads each, so that explains the duplicates

What's the limit set to? You can query SELECT @@max_prepared_stmt_count; The default should be 16384, but it might be configured to something else.

Looking at the source code prepared statements appear to be disabled by default. This means their usage in you application seems to have been a conscious choice. Maybe determine if there is a specific reason this choice was made and if it is actually necessary?

@BillKarwin we actually bumped the limit to 64k once we started seeing those errors.
@engineersmnky unfortunately whoever enabled in database.yml is long gone and there's no reasoning in git history.
I actually managed to reduce the number by a significant amount by finding some statements that were being created with hardcoded statements by changing queries like where(User[:created_at] < Time.now) to .where('created_at > ?', Time.now)
